# Facing issue while initiating variable

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-web, dart-null-safety

Is there any mistake related to initialization of EXId variable? Its giving me this error:Another exception was thrown: LateInitializationError: Field 'ExId' has not been initialized.

```
String? selectedValue;

  late final int dID;
  late final int staff_Id;

  late final int ExId;

  late String executiveName;

  List<UserLogin> allUsers = [];

  @override
  void dispose() {
    aptStatusController.dispose();
    partyTypeController.dispose();
    paymentModeController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    init();
  }

  Future init() async {
    final allUsrs = await LoginController.users();
    setState(() {
      this.allUsers = allUsrs;
      for (int i = 0; i < allUsrs.length; i++) {
        this.staff_Id == allUsrs[i].userId;
        this.executiveName == allUsrs[i].userName;

        if (aptExecutiveController.text == this.executiveName) {
          setState(() {
            ExId == this.staff_Id;
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`late` keyword is use to declare variables that will be initialized later. These are called non-nullable variables as they are initialized after the declaration.

**Note:** Once we declare a non-nullable `late` variable, the variable can't be null at runtime.

As you are initializing `ExId` variable inside an `if` condition. So there may be a case when `if` condition doesn’t execute, results in `ExId` nullable and thus breaking the `late` keyword constraint.

Try to declare `ExId` like this:

```
int? ExId;
```